# Custom quote formatting

Tags: horizontal-alignment, formatting, quoting

I have a `.cls` in which I have quite a bit of formatting... I'm trying to make a way of making my own "quote" formatting. I need to format my quotes centered, with a limited width for each line, and underlined (like a quote box). Should I do this with a custom `\begin{}` type? How do I do this?

Comment: [Welcome to TX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)!

Comment: Have you looked at the possibilities of the [csquotes](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/csquotes) package? Maybe `\fbox{\blockquote{...}}` is alredy enough.

Comment: Do you want a box around the quote or every word of the quote underlined?

Comment: I'd use a `newenvironment` for this, and base it on a `list`.... do you want every line underlined, or just the first? last?